# displaying other form inside DetailView in django

Tags: django

I have the detail view of "part" in views.py

```
class part_detail_view(DetailView):
    model = part_list
    context_object_name = 'part_detail'
    template_name = 'part_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(part_detail_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_list'] = populate_nav_bar()
        return context
```

but inside this URL I also want to display another form "CreateView" of the stock model so that from the same page I can display the form to add stock of the part and add the stock. This was done easily in function based view but I am not sure how to do this in class based view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create your form explicitly in forms.py:

```
# forms.py
class ParForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Part  # Your Part model
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then just inject the form into the context in `get_context_data()`:

```
# views.py
class PartDetailView(DetailView):
    ...
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['part_form'] = PartForm()  # Your part form
        return context
```

Then render the form in template:

```
...
<form method="post" action="{% url 'create_part' %}">
    {{ part_form }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
...
```

where `create_part` is the url of your CreateView.

Comment: doesn't   create view create own form from the model ? i didn't pass any form in create view

Comment: In CreateView Django implicitly injects default form as `context['form']`. But not for DetailView, so you must explicitly write the form and add it to context, see updated answer.

Comment: in id field, it shows all the parent element how can it be pre-filled to an id and hide it?

Comment: To make a hidden field add `widgets = {'id': forms.HiddenInput()}` to `Meta` class. But Django does this by default, I don't understand how you made it not hidden.

Comment: I am talking about id of its parent element to be pre filled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148688/discussion-between-vlad-t-and-rajiv-shah).