# Django : add CreateView to DetailedView of related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am very new to Django and trying to build a job posting site. I am currently stucked. I want to add `JobsAppliedCreateView` inside `JobsDetailedView`, so that they show up on the same template. When the form from JobsApplied template get saved, it will be saved to the database.

I have tried the include tags but no luck.

My `Views` looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from job_post.models import JobPost, JobsApplied


class JobsCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  model = JobPost
  template_name = 'job_post.html'
  fields = '__all__'
  permission_required = 'job_post.view_jobpost'

     def form_valid(self, form):
       form.instance.author = self.request.user
       return super().form_valid(form)


class JobsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = JobPost
    template_name = 'job_post-detail.html'


class JobsListView(ListView):
    model = JobPost
    template_name = 'job_post-list.html'


class JobAppliedCreateView(CreateView):
    model = JobsApplied
    template_name = 'job_post_jobapplied.html'
    fields = '__all__'

      def form_valid(self, form):
         form.instance.customuser = self.request.user
         return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Well, instead of trying mixing the class based views, just use `get_context_data` in your   `JobsAppliedCreateView`, pass the pk as argument and retrieve the object detail you want.

Comment: The JobsAppliedCreateView is meant to be the same and at the bottom of all DetailedView. Will it still work

Comment: For anyone looking for a similar solution. I used this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985709/displaying-other-form-inside-detailview-in-django and it worked.